# $112x\equiv392\pmod{91}$ has $7$ solutions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

**True or false? $112x\equiv392\pmod{91}$ has exactly $7$ solutions.**

---

A necessary and sufficient condition for a linear congruence equation to have solution says that $\gcd(112,91)\mid392$, and the solutions are $\gcd(112,91)=7$. Since $7\mid392$ then the statement is true.

Is it correct? Am I supposed to find the general solution $(x=10+91k,\;0\leq k<7)$?

Thanks!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork that is not the exactly words of the statement. You are adding some text that is not in the original statement.

Comment: I added a single word which (I thought) clarified the problem.  If the mathematical problem has exactly $8$ distinct solutions, is the answer to your question "yes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $91=13\cdot 7$ we have that

$$112x\equiv392\pmod{91} \iff 21x\equiv 28\pmod{91}$$

is equivalent to

$$21x\equiv 28\pmod{7} \iff 0\equiv 0 \pmod{7}$$

$$21x\equiv 28\pmod{13} \iff 8x\equiv 2\pmod{13}\iff 4x\equiv 1\pmod{13}$$

and for the latter since $10\cdot4-3\cdot13=1$ we have

$$10\cdot 4x\equiv 10\cdot 1\pmod{13}\iff x\equiv 10\pmod{13}$$

therefore the $7$ positive solutions less than $91$ are

$$x\in\{10,23,36,49,62,75,88\}$$

Comment: How did you know that $5$ and $8$ must be here: "and since $5\cdot21-8\cdot13=1$"?

Comment: By Bezout identity since$ (13,21)=1$ by Euclidean algorithm we can find that $5\cdot21-8\cdot13=1$ and therefore $5$ is the inverse of $21 \mod 13$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how you go from $21x\equiv28\color{red}{\pmod{91}}$ to $21x\equiv28\color{red}{\pmod{7}}$. From $21x\equiv28\pmod{91}$ I say that $\gcd(21,91)=7\wedge7\mid28\Rightarrow\frac{21}7x\equiv\frac{28}7\pmod{\frac{91}7}$, so the equation becomes $3x\equiv4\pmod{13}$. So the solution is $x_0=3^{\varphi(13)-1}4=3^{11}4\equiv10\pmod{13}$. So the general solution is $x=10+91k,\;0\leq k<7$, so the statement is correct. Am I ok?

Comment: @manooooh from $a \equiv b \mod pq$ so that $a=b+pqn$ you can deduce $a\equiv b \mod p$

Comment: And I don't see the Bezout Identity in my course `:(`.

Comment: @MarkBennet thanks, but I don't see the deduction. Is my reasoning ok in my previous comment? Do you wanna to see it in the original question?

Comment: @manooooh It is a bit strange that you have not seen Bezout identity, are you sure about that, maybe you have called that in another way https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity

Comment: @manooooh The given equation $ax=b \pmod{7\cdot 13}$ is equivalent to the system $ax=b \pmod{7}$ and $ax=b \pmod{13}$. Since the first one is trivially satisfied all reduces to the second one.

Comment: @manooooh $a=b+pqn$ tells us that $a$ and $b$ differ by a multiple of $p$. I am not trying to answer your question because I think that would be confusing in a comment. There are various techniques available in circumstances like this - and Bezout/Euclidean Algorithm will be worth knowing if you don't already know them. gimusi is pointing you in a direction which will prove mathematically productive.

Comment: Thank you all! So @gimusi, the statement is correct I think, no? If so, why in the Servaes answer he says "and it is quickly verified that this does not have $7$ solutions, but only one"? Is it true or not?

Comment: @manooooh You ar ewelocme. We have infinitely many solutions that is $x=10+13k$ and only 7 between $0$ and $91$. I don't understand the conlcusion by Servaes you might ask to him/her for further explanations about that.

Comment: @manooooh Maybe Servaes is referring to only one solution $\pmod{13}$.

Comment: @manooooh I've simplified the derivation for the second part reducing $21x\equiv 28\pmod{13}$ to $4x\equiv 1\pmod{13}$.

Comment: @gimusi ok. The equation $x=10+91k,0\leq k<7$ is incorrect because all the solutions for differents values of $k\neq0$ don't satisfy that them are not in $\mathbb Z_{91}$? I mean, for example if $k=1$ then $x=10+91=101\not\in\mathbb Z_{91}$. This equation is wrong?

Comment: @manooooh $x=10+91k$ are solutions but not all the solutions, we are loosing 23,39, etc. in that way

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it is a necessary and sufficient condition that $\gcd(112,91)\mid392$, and indeed it is satisfied. But this does not imply that the congruence has $7$ solutions. It only implies that it has *some* solutions; the condition does not tell you *how many* solutions there are.

Because $112$, $392$ and $91$ are all multiples of $7$, solving the congruence comes down to solving
$$112x=392+91k\qquad\text{ or equivalently }\qquad 16x=56+13k,$$
so it suffices to solve the congruence $16x\equiv56\pmod{13}$. This can be further reduced to 
$$3x\equiv4\pmod{13},$$
and it is quickly verified that this *does not* have $7$ solutions, but only  one.

Comment: from $3x\equiv7\pmod{13}$ we obtain x=11 which doesn't satisfy $112x\equiv392\pmod{91}$ indeed $112\cdot 11\equiv 49 \pmod{91}$

Comment: @gimusi Thanks for the catch, that $7$ should have been a $4$, corrected now.

Comment: @Servaes thank you! So the answer would be "False. It has only one solution in $\mathbb Z_{91}$"?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right!